# Hide <label> dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, label

How do I hide a certain label dynamically along with it's leading th tag?

example:

```
<th class="woo_metabox_names"><label for="woothemes_size">sq ft</label></th>
```

I tried and this doesn't work, by the way:

```
$('label[for="woothemes_size"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide both the `label` and `th` elements, you can use:

```
$('label[for="woothemes_size"]').parent().hide();
```

Comment: Why bother hiding the child element? It will be hidden with the parent

Comment: @Phil Ha! Good point. Can't believe I didn't see that. Although there might be some reason why you'd want to hide both individually (since what it really does is change the `display` to `none` for each element that `hide` is called on), but you're probably right.

Comment: $('label[for="woothemes_size"]').closest('th').hide();  should be good enough right ??

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yeah that works too. I don't know which is better. I like using things that assume certain things about the structure of the DOM